# XCode Command Line App and Free Pascal Compiler

Tags: xcode, freepascal, fpc

I need to build a quick command line app on my mac using xcode and I want to use the free pascal compiler instead of the c/c++ in XCode how do I change XCode's settings to use this. (sorry if its a basic question I'm used to developing in Delphi on windows)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This site has a detailed tutorial:

```
http://pascal-central.com/fp-xcode/
```